# selecting best row by optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have a two dimensional array which looks like this:

```
243 432
342 540
150 250
430 100
.   .
.   .
.   .
.   .
```

Now I have to select one "full row" from the given 2d array which is the "best". "Best" is defined as selecting a row in which first column is maximum(or nearest to maximum) of all values in first column and second column is minimum(or nearest to minimum) of all values in second column.

Is there any optimal way of performing this operation, preferably in python?

EDIT: the second column has more weight during selection of row

Comment: Do you have a better measure - the one you have isn't very clear?  Could you just take the difference of the first column and second column and find the maximum value?

Comment: "Best" is not defined precisely. What is best if a row has the second highest and second lowest values and a different row has the highest and third lowest values? Does the answer to the previous question depend on the distance to the maximum/minimum of any of those values?

Comment: the second column has more weight during selection.

Comment: Let's say you hand me a piece of paper with the array data printed on it. What would be your instructions to me so that I could find the "best" row without needing to ask you any more questions?

Comment: It should be : find the row for which first value is maximum in its column (or is closest to the maximum) and second value is minimum for its respective column (or closest to the minimum). *() = where exact pair is not available

Answer (score 2):

Why not sort it and take the first value? [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sorted) can take a key function which provides a value to sort on.

```
myData = [                                                                       
    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],                                                        
    [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1],                                                        
    [1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2],                                                        
    [1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 4.3]                                                         
]
w1 = 1    # First column weight
w2 = 2    # Second column weight                                                       

myRow = sorted(myData, key=lambda x: w2 * x[1] - w1 * x[0])[0]                         
print(myRow)
```

Without any restrictions on the data, you can't do this in anything faster than linear time.

Comment: This fails on `myData = [[1.0, 2.0], [1.1, 2.0]]`

Comment: @jazzpi Fails as in? That data gives me `[1.1, 2.0]` which is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: It gives me `[1.0, 2.0]`. Are you sure you copied your exact code? Since a `reverse=True` gives the right result for me.

Comment: @jazzpi you're right, swapped the indicies when typing into SO. Thanks for the catch, its edited.

Comment: The 'sorted' will sort the whole array based on the condition, which is nlogn. But, you do not need to sort, you just need the 'best' row. So, go through each row and return the max of calculated by the  condition: w2 * x[1] - w1 * x[0]

Answer (score 0):

1. Let maxval be max(col0) and minval - min(col1)
2. Sort rows inside your matrix using the sort function below
3. Take the first item of sorted array

```py
def mycmp(a, b):
    ret = cmp(a[1] - minval, b[1] - minval)
    if ret != 0:
        return ret

    return cmp(maxval - a[0], maxval - b[0])

matrix.sort(cmp=mycmp)
print "Optimal: ", matrix[0]
```

Comment: Note that `list.sort` sorts the list in-place which might be inconvenient. Usually it's more convenient to use `sorted` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort by second column ascending
2. Select all rows that are minimal in the second column (they are coming first in the sorted array)
3. Sort those rows descending by first column
4. The first row is you "best".

If this is not what you want, you need to specify more precisely when to trade off a less minimal second column value for a more maximal first row one.

If you are unable to sort only a portion of an array (step 3), you could also use the steps 3, 1, 4 instead as long as your sort is stable.

Note that this is NOT the optimal algorithm but it gets reasonably close.